# Display Error message at the Right End margin in editText as show in Screenshot below

Tags: android

[image]

I want to display the error message as shown in the screenshot.Whenever there is en error I want to display error message and if everything thing correct then not to display the error message.I don't want pop up . Eg. editText.setError();

Comment: I prefer to use frame layout , then put edittext and textview together..u can set error in that  textview ..

Comment: ok will try n check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
String errorMsg = "invalid email";
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setError(errorMsg);
```

Hope this will hepl you.

Comment: I don't want seterror(""); i Want exactly the same as in the design.

Comment: Ok, then use TextView at the right of your EditText and use textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) when you want to show error message and don't forget to do textView.setVisibility(View.GONE) when required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new support library features http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#
If you are using studio add this `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/fNameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="First Name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want seterror(""); i Want exactly the same as in the design.

Comment: Will it work in eclipse ? i've been working with eclipse.